# Backbone Routes - trigger route on page load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, marionette

This is a simple question, but I am new to routing and haven't been able to find an answer to this.

I have a Marionette Router (if I intimidate you, its really the same thing as a Backbone Router. Very simple).

```
sys.routes = {
  "app/:id": "onAppRoute",
};

sys.Router = new Marionette.AppRouter({
  controller: {
    onAppRoute: function(route) {
      console.log('Called app route!');
    },
  },
  appRoutes: sys.routes,
});

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
```

This works - if you hit the back button my browser, the url will change within my Single Page Application and will call the `onAppRoute` function.

However, let's say I open a new browser window and paste in my page url to a certain 'app':

```
http://localhost/app/myApplication
```

This doesn't call the `onAppRoute` function. It doesn't even seem like it should, though, but I really don't know.

#### I want it to.

I don't know if I am doing it wrong, or if I should just manually fire it by grabbing my page url on page load, parsing it, then 'navigating' to that route. Seems hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to your intuition, backbone's default behaviour is to trigger matching routes on page load! cf. http://backbonejs.org/#Router - look for the option `silent: true`. You'd have to specify that for the router to IGNORE your matching routes on page load, i.e. not trigger the corresponding callbacks.

So your problem lies somewhere else: your routes do NOT match the url you have stated as an example. Clearly, you require an `:id` parameter, trailing `http://localhost/app/myApplication`. Therefore, `http://localhost/app/myApplication/213` would cause your callback to be triggered on page load, given you didn't pass `silent: true` as an option to `backbone.history.start()`.

If you want to match the 'root' url, i.e. no params, you would define the following route:

```
routes: {
    '/': someFunction
}
```

Comment: Thanks and you are correct - after a few hours yesterday I saw I was somehow routing it improperly. Note - I did have an `id` - that's `myApplication`, but you were pointing in the right direction. Its good to know this for certain - thanks.

Comment: John Spartan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017210/router-js-function-not-executed Can you help me out here? :D

Comment: Maybe it changed, but it seems you have to define the default route using an empty string instead of '/'.

Answer (score 0):

The :id part is a parameter, which will be extracted by Backbone.Router and sent as an argument to onAppRoute.
 But in your URL you don't have any parameters /localhost/app/myApplication